# Downloading a page using OpenSSL send - Python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, get, connection

I'm using `pyOpenSSL` library establish connection. 
Here's how I create the connection:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(5)
self.context = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
self.connection = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(context, s)
self.connection.connect((url, SSL_PORT))
```

pretty trivial. Now I want to send a `GET` request to a url, and download its page:

```
def send(self, url):
    if not self.connection:
        log.warning("Connection not stablished")
        return None
    else:
        request = "GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: www.google.com"
        self.connection.send(request)
        log.info("Server response")
        log.info("-" * 40)
        resp = self.connection.recv(4096)
        while (len(resp) > 0):
            log.info(resp)
            resp = self.connection.recv(4096)
        return resp
```

However I'm getting a `HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT`:

```
  File "./scurl", line 125, in send
    log.info(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1320, in recv
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1167, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise ZeroReturnError()
OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError
```

What's the correct way to download the page content?

***Rules: **** I cannot use other libraries. Yes, it's for a homework. I'm just having trouble with the `request`. Could someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the HTTP GET request looks invalid. It should be:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n
```

Note the carriage return (`'\r'`) and new line (`'\n'`) characters at the end of each line. You can store this as a string like this:

```
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"
```

Because the request is not properly terminated, the remote server will wait for the rest of the request, and will eventually timeout with a HTTP 408 response.

---

Another problem could be that you are possibly reading from a different connection. You send using the instance member `self.connection`:

```
self.connection.send(request)
```

But try to read the response on what seems to be a global variable:

```
resp = connection.recv(4096)
```

Comment: Even though I added the request as you mentioned, and I read until there's nothing in the buffer, I'm still getting "OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError"

Comment: @philippe: another potential problem - see updated answer.

Comment: @philippe: I can get your code to work, but only if I remove the call to `settimeout(5)`. What happens if you try that?